# Collections optimized for concurrency in .Net

Tags: .net, collections, concurrency

In the java world there is a set of [classes](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) optimized for concurrent tasks. I assume there is something similar in .Net, but after a quick search in MSDN I couldn't find anything. I was looking for a queue with fairness policy to be used in consumer/producer situations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Parallels Library for .NET contains some thread-safe collections.

One of them is a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`

http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/archive/2008/08/12/8852005.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Surely an oxymoron? Collections that are thread-safe will probably aquire more locks than required. To optimise one usually defines the locks in a higher location.

Answer (score 0):

The non-generic .NET collections (System.Collections namespace) can all do this. I've nicked the following snippet from [MSDN Queue.SyncRoot page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.syncroot.aspx):

```
Queue myCollection = new Queue();

lock(myCollection.SyncRoot)
{
   foreach (Object item in myCollection)
   {
      // Insert your code here.
   }
}
```

Or you can just create a synchronized wrapper right away:

```
Queue mySyncCollection = Queue.Synchronized(myCollection);
// No locks required
```

Unfortunately this is not possible to do with the generic collections so probably you will have to write your own wrappers / extension methods if you want to use generic collections.

Comment: Your synchronized statement locks on the instance of the class which can lead to deadlocks and other bad things!

Comment: Henrik: Are you sure? This is not like, locking on the instance of the collection. That's the whole point. As I've said, I've stolen the examples from MSDN anyway.